# Alamofire: ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'Result<_,_>' to type 'Result'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

I am using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for sending request and handling response. I created a simple class which uses `Alamofire.Result` type:

```
class MyHandler {
    private var _result: Alamofire.Result

    init(result: Alamofire.Result) {
        //ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'Result<_,_>' to type 'Result'
        self._result = result
    }
}
```

}

I am getting a weird error as shown above in my code. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Result.swift) of `Alamofire.Result` . It is a Enum `enum Result<Value, Error: ErrorType>`.

I am using the same `Alamofire.Result` type in my class for `self._result` & the `result` passed in initialier.

Why am I getting this error? it looks like compiler doesn't think they are the same type...  my xcode version is 7.3.1. Is this a xcode bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AlamoFire.Result` is a generic type with two placeholders

```
public enum Result<Value, Error: ErrorType> { ... }
```

You can declare your class for concrete types for the
placeholders, for example

```
class MyHandler {
    private var _result: AlamoFire.Result<Int, NSError>

    init(result: AlamoFire.Result<Int, NSError>) {
        self._result = result
    }
}
```

But it is more likely that you want to declare a generic class:

```
class MyHandler<Value, Error: ErrorType> {
    private var _result: AlamoFire.Result<Value, Error>

    init(result: AlamoFire.Result<Value, Error>) {
        self._result = result
    }
}
```